# Keep all windows open when unplugging removing external storage. (stealthily eject flash drive)

Tags: usb, filemanager, eject

When pulling a flash drive, SD card or ejecting a disc, opened file manager windows close automatically.

Sometimes, I just quickly need to unplug it to transfer data from a different computer, and I would like to keep the windows open as if the programs do not notice that the device was removed.

#### How can I remove a USB stick without programs responding to it by closing windows, etc. ?

Comment: Are they only closing when you have selected the drive and were viewing the contents of it?  That is usually what happens to me.  If I am viewing another folder and pull the drive the application doesn't close.

Comment: @Terrance This is my case as well.

Comment: I think the answer below is correct.  I just tested it on my system.  I currently have version 3.26.4 installed.  It returned to an empty folder state without closing.  It was an older version that did that to me.  I think that one of the file managers recently was still doing it to me, but I would have to test each one individually.

Answer (score 3):

It was an old nautilus behavior which cannot be tweaked.
(Can be tweaked in current nemo, though.)

After 13.04(up to now), nautilus will get back home if opened drive is unmounted.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2156088

I suppose you're using a very old distribution?

Comment: No, I use a very young distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. So far, the only method I've found that works is to open the flash drive in a new window from the file manager, and then eject it from that window. It closes the current window but keeps the original window open. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, J.Knight. Welcome to StackExchange. If you get downvoted by anyone, do not take it personally. (I did not downvote.) It is really easy to get ravenous downvotes on StackExchange, and the users often refuse to explain their downvote. I am just preparing you. But thank you for your contribution.

Comment: On StackExchange, even some moderators do not comply with their code of conduct. https://askubuntu.com/conduct